# Websites from one web host are inaccessible and can't figure out why

Tags: networking

A friend of mine is experiencing a strange networking issue, and I'm starting to suspect the problem is on the remote host. He is unable to connect to any websites that are hosted by one particular local web hosting provider. This includes connecting to an e-mail server which is hosted through this local provider.

I am able to connect successfully if I go through my VPN on his devices, and he is able to connect if he connects through my LTE hotspot. But he cannot connect to any of the sites on his home WiFi (ISP: Verizon FiOS) or his work WiFi (ISP: Comcast Xfinity). All of his devices are Apple products, but I tried connecting to his WiFi using my Android phone and experienced the same issue.

Here's some of the things I've tried:

- Tried changing DNS servers (Google and OpenDNS)
- Tried pinging both the domain name and IP address of one of the sites
- Tried navigating directly to the resolved IP address
- Tried two different ISPs (Comcast Xfinity and Verizon FiOS, but it does work on Verizon LTE)
- Tried four different devices (2-MacOS X, iOS, and Android)
- Tried disabling IPv6
- Checked firewall rules and ACLs on the home router and host-based firewall on the Mac
- Tried changing user agent

DNS lookup works fine using `host` and `nslookup`. But I cannot ping or connect to the sites on ports 80 or 443 unless I connect through my VPN or hotspot.

Is there anything else I should be trying locally? The fact that this is occurring with two separate ISPs is a little baffling. The only other thing I can think of is something is being blocked at the point of the remote server. Interestingly, I have Comcast Xfinity at home and I have no issues connecting to any of this host's sites myself.

Could it perhaps be a range of IP addresses blocked for some reason?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the security software on the computer and the firewall?

Comment: Do you know if other devices from _work Wi-Fi_ can access the site? Can you run `tcpdump -n -i en0` (or en1, or en2, or whatever one corresponds to the Wi-Fi interface on macOS) and make sure your pings and/or connection attempts at least go out from the computer itself?

Comment: Pings are going out and I'm able to ping and access other sites fine. Just no sites by the one web host. I also disabled the firewall and tried it, but no luck.